# How to copy a file with filename "+" and rename it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, copy, rename

I have a file named  +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG  on a linux server (Please don't ask me how it got there as I have no idea how it got there). I wish to rename it to 13x18_DSC_0800.JPG. However I have not been able to. When I try to copy it I get ;

```
# cp \+13x18_DSC_0800.JPG asd.JPG
  cp: cannot stat `+13x18_DSC_0800.JPG': No such file or directory
```

Here is some more inforamtion ;

```
#ll
 -rwxrwxrwx  1 ftpuser renko 2798985 2011-10-14 01:12  +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG*
```

I really don't know what is wrong other than that the plus sign is killing some script. 
Some more information ;

```
#uname -a
Linux server-1 2.6.38-8-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be awesome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often this means there are some non-printing characters in the filename, which you can't see because they're non-printing.

Try `ls -la > /tmp/foo` then `vi -b /tmp/foo` to look at all the text.

If that's the case, the easiest way is to handle it via glob, try `echo *13x18_DSC_0800*` to verify that the glob matches that file (and only that file), then you can do `mv *13x18_DSC_0800* newname.jpeg` to rename it.

Comment: Or `ls -la | cat -vT`

Comment: @MadHatter I got a "-rwxrwxrwx  1 ftpuser renko 2798985 2011-10-14 01:12  +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ftpuser renko 2567144 2011-10-14 01:12  +13x18_DSC_0848.JPG
"

Comment: @MadHatter Although I haven't been able to resolve this issue without using the joker card i.e. "*". Here is the solution I have been able to find ;


      #cp *DSC_0800* 13x18_DSC_0800.JPG
      #rm *+*

This seems to do the trick... I still wonder why I couldn't do it without using the * ....
Since you reminded me of the * you get the bonus!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cp "+13x18_DSC_0800.JPG" 13x18_DSC_0800.JPG
```

Comment: Sorry but no cigar you get a : "cp: cannot stat `+13x18_DSC_0800.JPG': No such file or directory" error

Answer (score 0):

stupid and simple solution if you want to get rid of just one file - use midnight commander :D

but + sign at the beginning shouldn't be a problem at all ...

```
    $ touch +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG
    $ mv +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG test.jpg
    $ rm test.jpg
```

works for me ...

Comment: [edited] actually it did not work... the test.jpg turned out to be a 0 byte file...

Comment: touch does create an empty file with that name if it does not exist. i was presenting this as an example of it working.

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
    cp +13x18_DSC_0800.JPG 13x18_DSC_0800.JPG
```

worked like charm, without any escaping.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses globbing and so requires checking only one file matches. If we prepend a path the reference is unique.

```
touch +plus.file
touch -minus.file
mv ./+plus.file plus.file
mv ./-minus.file minus.file
```